# BigQuery UDF & String.prototype.indexOf()

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) in a BigQuery UDF to check if one String contains another i.e. use basic JavaScript.

But it gives me this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That means `s` is undefined.

Comment: yeah - how are you calling decodeHelper?

Comment: Thanks guys. See my answer. I forgot my table in BigQuery had null values. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't take into consideration that my incoming table row in BigQuery might have `null` values.

Easy fix by just checking `s`:

```
function decodeHelper(s) {
  if(s){
      if(s.indexOf("foo") > -1){
         return "true";
      }else{
         return "false";
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you then deal with result of decodeHelper, you might consider below option

```
function decodeHelper(s) {
  if(s){
      if(s.indexOf("b") > -1){
         return "true";
      }else{
         return "false";
      }
  }else{
      return "false";
  }  
}
```